# How to add 3D graphics in windowsform as a panel in C# using visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, 3d, opentk

[image]
I want to add OpenTK library in my project to have 3D GUI instead of 2D as a panel. The green area is the panel that i intent to put the 3D in. Is that possible to use openTk library as a panel? "not windowsform." I am using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions! You should at least provide us with minimum effort from your side of what you have tried to solve your problem.

Comment: You can use the `OpenTK.GLControl` instead of the panel.